# "Any object in A and B"—What does it mean?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, semantics, logic

Does "any object in A and B" in English mean

1. any object in A and any object in B;
2. any object in A or any object in B; or
3. any object in the intersection of A and B?
   Thanks a lot.

Another question is that if one wants to express 1, should it be "any object in A or B", or is there another simpler way to express 1? Thanks a lot.

Any helpful answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would definitely not mean **or** (2) and probably does not mean 3. For three one would say "any objects in *both* A and B." (And please note that the statement itself is in English, so your title is a bit of a puzzlement.)

Comment: In general English, it is ambiguous and could mean any of several things. When expressing logical relationships in words, much more detail is needed than this.

Comment: I would understand it to mean any object that appears in set A as well as in set B.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I am wondering, what is a simpler way to express 1? Thank you very much.

Comment: A simpler way to express (1) is _any object in the intersection of A and B_. That's precise. English isn't. The English conjunction _and_ is not the same thing as the dyadic functor `And`.

Answer (score 2):

In mathematical terms, "any object in A and B" expresses x in A and B at the same time. So definitely 3 -- intersection of A and B.

With respect to:

> any object in A and any object in B

... think any x in A and any y in B.

> any object in A or any object in B

... think any x in A or any y in B.

> any object in A or B

... think any x in A or B. (Very much like you expressed it.)

Aside: in that last one, be wary that there is an ambiguity, because the logical OR (as in A or B, one or the other or both) is not a XOR (exclusive OR, as in A *or* B, but not both). That *but not both* is a way to resolve this in "layman" speech, but seeing how most people confuse OR and XOR you're usually better off also writing *or both* to make the logical OR explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The most well known context in which I think #1 occurs is the stereotypical Chinese menu, where diners could create a fixed-price, family-style meal by choosing items from different categories (appetizers, entrees, etc.). This was typically expressed as *Choose 1 from Column A, 2 from Column B, ...*. Conjunctions like *and* and *or* were avoided to prevent ambiguity.